# what API square iphone card reader is using?

Tags: ios4

I am new to iphone developement I am wondering hows square card reader iphone app works ? 
Can any body explain what api it's using to transmit the card information from audio input to app ?  rest is really simple .

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok let me answer my question myself . I am able to decode CC both from Android and Iphone using Square reader . firstly you need to record the audio coming from audio jack in 4400 pcm no big Indian format then you have to identify the peak points in audio (Treat them as 1's ) and weak points as 0's at the end you will have the binary representation of data for that search for Credit Card ABA format ,remember you are reading track2

Comment: This might haved worked for on of the earliest version of the Square reader, but now card information is encrypted in the reader so this approach wouldn't be as viable.